# Common Controls Plugins for MFC like in c#?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I'm working with MFC VC++ Application. I would like to use simple UI like in c# NumericUpdown & openFile Dialog & SavefileDialog etc in my application. I would like to know is there any wrapper or plugin for MFC to do this process? Because it is too messy to add a simple control using MFC when comparing to C# .Net! Is there library or plugin to reduce this task? Preferably a free one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it is too messy".  MFC provides many classes to handle what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just don't know how to do it? In an MFC app controls are easily added by dragging them from a toolbar onto a dialog template. That is the "Visual" part of Visual C++.

And the open and save dialog are available using MFC class CFileDialog.